# Data insertion to mongodb with mongoose and angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm new to nodejs and dived into using mongoose for mongodb. Let me show you the code structure that I made knowing that I'm doing a mistake somewhere. Suppose from angular using `$http.post` I'm sending an object to be inserted into db. The way I'm trying to insert the data into the database doesn't seem to work.

```
Mongoose Schema Contacts.js

    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/contactlist');

    var ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        email : String,
        number : String
    }, {collection:'contactlist'});

    var ContactModel = mongoose.model('ContactList', ContactSchema);

    module.exports = ContactModel; 

Node server.js

    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    var db = require('./model/Contacts.js');
    var contact = new db();

    require('./routes/routes.js')(app, db, contact);

Node routes.js

    module.exports = function(app, db, contact){


        // post api

        app.post('/contacts', function(req,res){

            var body = req.body;

            contact.save(body, function(err, data){
                res.json(data);
            });

        });

    };
```

I'm messing up somewhere with inserting the data into database specially with the `new db()` and passing it to the `routes` file. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. And how can I improve these scripts after the insertion is solved?

Comment: Since you're not using db or contact vars in routes.js you can omit them. If you're using req.body then you should be using bodyParser middleware.

Comment: I'm using bodyParser middleware.  I just didn't show that in the code. I'm using db and contact vars in routes.js. I'm passing it through the function.  I'm getting the data using db. But I'm just unable to insert the data.

Comment: without going into details about question, i don't see that your app is listening for incoming requests, ```app.listen```

Comment: @Srle It is. I didn't put everything in the code which are common. Just the parts that I was having difficulty with.

Comment: @nickB so any further question? Did you have a time to try any of the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Mongoose Schema Contacts.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email : String,
    number : String
}, {collection:'contactlist'});

var ContactModel = mongoose.model('ContactList', ContactSchema);

module.exports = ContactModel;
```

Node server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
var contacts = require('./model/Contacts.js');

require('./routes/routes.js')(app);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/contactlist');
```

Node routes.js

```
var contacts = require('./model/Contacts.js');
module.exports = function(app){
    // post api
    app.post('/contacts', function(req,res){

        var body = req.body;

// not sure about contact vs contacts here
        contact.save(body, function(err, data){
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As part of `server.js` you are creating document, i.e instance of mongoose model and after that you are passing that document to exported function of `routes.js` module. From there you are "victim" of javascript closures. Inside of *'/contacts'* route handler `contact` will always be the same thing (document that you passed from `server.js`).

Then in your route handler you are using mongoose `.save()` method in a wrong way, providing data which you want to save as a first parameter. 
Please read: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save,

Now lets try to **force** your example to work and see what will happen, surely thing that you didn't want to happen.

```
module.exports = function(app, db, contact) {
    app.post('/contacts', function(req,res){    
        contact.name = req.body.name;
        contact.email = req.body.email;
        contact.number = req.body.number;

        contact.save(function(err, data){
          res.json(data);
        });
    });
};
```

With this you will end with updating always the same document, the document with same id in mongoose collection due to reasons explained at the beginning of the answer.

So what you want to do is to create new document whenever there is a POST to '/contacts'.

```
var Contact = require('path to Contact model');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.post('/constacts', function (req, res) {
    var contact = new Contact(req.body);
    contact.save(function(err) {
      if(err) {...}
      ...
    });
  });
};
```

By the way, move `mongoose.connection` logic out of your models, that needs to be part of bootstraping application logic and `db` is probably terrible name to be used for the purposes for which you are using it.